# Calculate estimated time in a program

Tags: c++

I'm making a program and I want to give to the user information about the estimated times every 1000 elements processed. I'm calculating time in this way:

- C = elements processed so far
- MAX = Max elements to process
- Tp = time elapsed
- Te = time estimated

In theory, the relation between elements processed and elapsed time is equal to the relation between the rest of the elements and the rest of time, so my formula is:

(C/Tp) = (MAX - C)/(Te - Tp)

So I need to solve **Te** by doing:

(Te - Tp) = (MAX - C)Tp/C

And finally:

Te = (MAX - C)Tp/C + Tp

I think that resolution is correct but clearly, operation doesn't tend to 0 as **C** and **Tp** grows, so I'm sure that I'm doing a stupid mistake but I couldn't find.

Some ideas please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your initial equation is slightly off, rather than what you have it should be

```
(C/Tp) = (MAX - C)/Te
```

since we're estimating the time required to process each item, and this should be constant and equal in the past and the future. This will give you a final equation

```
Te = (MAX - C)*(Tp/C)
```

which tends to zero as expected.

(This is assuming that `Te` is the estimated time *left*, not estimated total time)

Comment: This is exactly what I'm searching for: estimated time left

Answer (score 5):

I think it's fine. You're probably thinking about "time remaining", which in your case would be Tr = Te - Tp. That one does tend to 0.

Start: C = 0, results in divide by zero. Makes sense, you have no speed indication so there's no estimate.

End: C = MAX, MAX-C=0, so Te=Tp. Makes sense, estimate is now equal to elapsed time.

Halfway, C=MAX/2, MAX-C = C, so Te=C*Tp/C + Tp, or about twice the current amount passed. Makes sense.

One quarter, C = MAX/4, MAX-C=3*C, so Te=3*C*Tp / C + Tp, or Te = 4*Tp. Makes sense, again.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't take the entire time that elapsed.

You should just take the  average of the last 4-5 chunks of 1000 objects. Because that will give you a more accurate idea of the current speed of calculation.

```
t1,t2,t3,t4 = last 4 calculations

thisIteration = timePassedSinceLastCheck/1000 //Avg time per object
Te = (Max-C)*Avg(t1,t2,t3,t4,thisIteration)
```

Comment: Good notice, but this depends really on the situation. Some processes will benefit from a global estimate (e.g many peaks but relatively stable mean) and some from a moving window (e.g. exponential processes, or files copied by incremental size or ...)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. Yours would give a better estimate given continually changing environments, as the "speed" would recover quickly after a period of slowness. The other will stabilize the final time and assume that the interruptions so far are representative of the future.

Comment: Well yea, depends on what kind of system your checking.